# Giving Apache2 write access to a user directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I want to give Apache2 write access to a directory in a users home directory so it can write logs etc.

The idea is that I add Apache2 to the users group:

```
sudo usermod -aG vagrant www-data
```

And then I simply give the directory to which I want Apache2 to be able to write "group" `write` and `execute` permissions:

```
chmod g+wx ./logs
```

However, this does not seem to work.

How do I add Apache2 to a users group and set the permissions correctly for write access?

Comment: Check permissions on parent directories to make sure they don't interfere and test/debug from command line not from apache

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Thanks. But check 'm for what?

Comment: Make sure apache's user can actually enter that directory. Higher level directory permissions can prevent that. That's why I said test from the command line... it will be more apparent. And if it works from the command line, and not from apache, then you know it's an apache problem.

Comment: May be you have enabled SELinux or apparmor. Usually I saw such problems on servers with enabled SELinux. Check it.

Answer (score -2):

You should enable the userdir module and then restart Apache:

```
$ sudo a2enmod userdir
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, check Apache log: /var/log/apache2/error.log

Check this for reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85311/apache2-userdir-enabled-but-still-have-no-access